# (Easy Fix) How to insert div via content.js Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-chrome-extension

I'm want to create an overlay via content script (content.js) for my google chrome extension. How should I do this?

Here is the code that executes the content script:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function() {
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id }, function (activeTabs) {
          activeTabs.map(function (tab) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'contentScript.js', allFrames: false });
          });
      });
  });
}, {url: [{urlMatches : 'https://mail.google.com/'}]});
```

Here is my contentScript.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpOverlay, false);


function setUpOverlay(){
//Set up overlay div in here
}
```

Comment: 1) You're injecting in the active tab but navigation may occur in any tab so you should use the `details.tabId` parameter of onCommitted listener, see the documentation, and remove getCurrent(), query(), activeMap. 2) Remove addEventListener and just call setUpOverlay() because content scripts run after DOMContentLoaded event by default anyway so it won't be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to use the chrome message api and pass a message to the content script to execute the code 
here is how it works:

```
//popup.js 

chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},(tabs)=>{
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,'execoverlay',(resp)=>{
       console.log(resp.msg)
    })
})

//contentScript.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{
  if(request==='execoverlay'){
   // your code goes here 

      sendMessage({msg:'recieved'})
  }
})
```